# TigerVNC Viewer on Windows 10 changing default options

Tags: windows, vnc-viewer, tigervnc

How do I change the default options when starting TigerVNC Viewer on Windows 10 ? I want `Full screen` to be enabled and `Pass system keys directory to server (full screen)` to be disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `regedit` and go to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\TigerVNC\vncviewer`. Set `Fullscreen` to 1 and `FullscreenSystemKeys` to 0.